# where template context comes from when using TemplateHTMLRenderer

Tags: rest, web, django-rest-framework

Where the data that is going to be used on the template comes from? Can't find it, `get` returning `Response({}, template_name='user_detail.html')` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template context data is the first parameter of the Response class. In you example you set empty dict as a context.

Context is the response data and can be passed like this:

```
Response({'username': user.username}, template_name='user_detail.html')
```

From docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer:

> The TemplateHTMLRenderer will create a RequestContext, using the response.data as the context dict, and determine a template name to use to render the context.

Comment: yes, in my case was ```def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response(data={}, template_name='foobar.html')
```